# TortoiseSVN lost my author name

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I use TortoiseSVN x64 on my Windows 8.1 x64 laptop, accessing a remote server. I was given a username and password to access a repository. After a while of using the TortoiseSVN client, I grew tired of entering my username and password all the time, and checked the "save authentication" checkbox. It seemed to work fine.

However, the other day, I realized that when I look in the log (TortoiseSVN -> Show log), on all my commits the author is empty. The commit message I wrote is shown, but there's no author. I am not allowed to edit it afterwards to enter my username, I get an error message.

I tried on another client on another computer, where I have not saved my details, and then it worked fine, my username appeared as author on my commit.

I've been trying to remove the saved credentials from my laptop, but to no avail. I tried removing the AppData/Roaming/Subversion/auth folder (which was empty anyway), but nothing happens and as soon as I interact with the repo again the folder is recreated, empty as before.

I tried going to TortoiseSVN -> Settings -> Saved Data, and there the "clear" buttons on "Authentication data" are both disabled.

I tried uninstalling TortoiseSVN, rebooting the computer, reinstalling it again, and checking out the whole repository anew (in a different location but on the same hard drive).

Any suggestions?

EDIT: Had this problem for 2 years now. Tried cleaning cache in APPDATA but it didn't help. The cache is empty anyway. Due to other problems with my laptop, I cleaned the hard drives and re-installed Windows on it last week, but as soon as I had installed TortoiseSVN and checked out my first repo, I was back at the same issue. How on earth can it remember it if the hard drive is clean?

Comment: As an additional information, I now saw that if looking at statistics, everyone else have their author names, but I show up as "(unknown)", so I don't have a name there either.

Comment: I have similar behavior.  I copied my repository to the Microsoft Sharepoint.  Ever since, the log messages and author don't appear in the log.

Comment: My log messages are recorded fine, it's just my author name that is missing.

Comment: Two years later, this is still an issue. I even re-installed Windows and cleaned my hard drives on my laptop (for other reasons), but this is still a problem.

Comment: you sure the problem is on tortoise (client) and not subversion (server)?

Comment: No, I'm not sure, but no one else has this problem on the same server, and my user doesn't have this problem when used on another client, as described above, which makes me think it's the client.

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling the Tortoise SVN and then manually remove all registry keys from the registry and then install a fresh copy. I would recommend TortoiseSVN_(64bit)_v1.7.7.msi which is by far the most stable version.

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, we will never find out if this is the solution, since I have now quit the job where I had this problem. If I run into this problem again in the future, I'll try this.
But isn't the registry cleared when re-installing Windows on wiped hard drives?

Comment: Nope, not in the case of tortoise SVN where it leaves the traces in the machine. These can be cleared if you uninstall the software using Your Uninstaller.